# C++ reading input from cin until the whole line has been read

Tags: c++, input, eof, cin

I have a while loop reading in a char 'c', I have a check to see if the the char is an operator; '+', '-', '/', or '*'. The while loop reads through character by character but it doesn't stop...if the last char inputed is '+' for example. It will stay in the loop with the char 'c' set to '+' forever.

```
stack<int> num;
char c;
int n,count=0,a,b;
while (cin>>c)
{
    if (c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '/' && c != '*')
     {
         cout << c << endl;
         n = (c - 48);
         num.push(n);
         cin >> c;
         count++;
     }
     else if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '*')
     {
         cout << "count is " << count << endl;
         if (count>1)
         {
            b =  num.top();
            a = num.top();
            num.pop();
            num.pop();

            if (c == '+')
            {
                num.push(a+b);
                count--;
            }
            else if (c == '-')
            {
                num.push(a+b);
                count--;
            }
            else if (c == '/')
            {
                if (b != 0)
                {
                    num.push(a/b);
                    count--;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "division by zero" << endl;
                    return(0);
                }
            }
            else if (c == '*')
            {
                num.push(a*b);
                count--;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "invalid input" << endl;
                return(0);          
            }
         }
         else
         {
             cout << "stack underflow" << c << endl;
             return(0);
         }
     }
     cout << c << endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not cl;ear enough.

Comment: Your question isn't clear and that loop should work just fine. @TeoZec he won't need a break statement there, the condition should work just fine.

Comment: why not use getline? `getline(cin, string)` then do stuff?

Comment: It does not stop when there is no more input, if the last char in the line of input is a '+' then it stays in the while loop doing calculations with the '+' forever instead of exiting the while once it has read everything.

Comment: @Raphael ok thanks. I hadn't understood the question. I'll remove my comment

Comment: @user3678093 can you post more of the code?

Comment: perhaps it is something in my calculations that is somehow throwing off what I want.

Comment: @user3678093; Include the `while` body in your question. It will help us to understand your question.

Comment: @user3678093 what haccks said. I don't know if you want to read through all chars with the loop and check them inside or if you want to break the loop on them...

Comment: Now with the additional code I think Teo's answer is what you wanted, you got a small bugs tho. Recheck what you do in your `'-'` case, you probably wanted `a-b` and not `a+b`.

Comment: I believe the problem is in my calculations within the while and not in in checking for EOF like I thought, I will accept the answer below and keep checking for the bug thanks

Comment: @user3678093 I posted an answer with two things that probably are bugs that I noticed, maybe they are the ones you're having problems with too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you clarified your question it's way clearer. And @TeoZec answer should be right. I just wanna note two things that seem buggy in your above code:

```
else if (c == '-')
{
    num.push(a+b);
    count--;
}
```

here you probably wanted `a-b` instead.

```
if (count>1)
{
    b =  num.top();
    a = num.top();
    num.pop();
    num.pop();
```

`b` and `a` will be the same number here, you should call `pop()` before getting the second number, like:

```
if (count>1)
{
    b =  num.top();
    num.pop();
    a = num.top();
    num.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have no condition to terminate your while loop, you will need to add either more conditions to your while like so:

```
while(cin>>c && c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '*' && c != '/')
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Or add a `break` to the inside of your while loop, after performing your checks to see what character was entered.

Comment: he has a condition in his loop tho. `cin>>c` will return false once it reaches eof and the loop will end.

Comment: thats what i thought, yet it isn't detecting the eof

Comment: Yes, but it will only exit the loop once it gets to the end of the line, not when it finds one of the characters he is looking for.

Comment: @user3678093 `cin >> c` stops at eof. Maybe you are mixed up between eof and eol.

Comment: Your answer might be actually what he wanted. I thought he wants to check the what `c` actually is inside the loop and wants the loop just to go through all characters. But breaking out of the loop on these characters might be possible too. The question is a bit unclear

Comment: The EOF character will not be created when you enter a line in the console. You would need to enter it manually by pressing CTRL-D, or the alternative is to add a break to your loop.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Very unclear.  He doesn't say when he wants to stop.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include <cstdio>
...

int c; // As pointed out by James Kanze in his comment, c should be an int to detect EOF
do {
    c = getchar();
    // Do stuff
} while ((c != '\n') && c != EOF))
```

You don't need to check just for EOF, but also for the line terminator.

Comment: `cin >> c` will never set `c` to `'\n'` (unless you unset `skipws`), so the second test will always evaluate to true.

Comment: @james so he could use getchar(), like in C. Thanks for noting, I'll correct it. But why won't cin set c to'\n'? I'm not an expert about C++, I would like some explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Your revised version won't work either; it will go into an endless loop at end of file.  As for not seeing the `'\n'`, `>>` is for formatted input (with one very special exception), and starts by skipping white space.  And `'\n'` is a white space characters.

Comment: @james ok, thanks for explanation. But I think the version with getchar() will work as long as we get the input from a keyboard. However, I'll fix it so that it will work also stdin is a file. Thanks for the explanation again.

Comment: The results of `getchar()` (which are the same as `std::cin::get()`) must be assigned to an `int`, not a `char`, before being tested; otherwise, you cannot detect end of file.  He could do: `for ( int c = getchar(); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = getchar() )`.  If he wants to keep `c` a `char`, he could do `while ( std::cin.get( c ) && c != '\n' )`.  In both cases, of course, he'd have to handle white space in the line himself, since it won't be stripped.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.  For starters,
I don't understand the purpose of the `cin >> c` in the `if`
branch; you input a character, but you never seem to use it;
it's just lost.  And of course, there's no need for the `if`
part in the `else if`, since it is the complement of the
condition of the `if`.  And of course, a `switch` is far more
natural that you `if/else if` chain when comparing a single
character against a number of different constants.  And of
course, `'0'` isn't always `48` (and even if it were, `'0'` is
a lot more readable than `48`).

As for staying in the loop with the char `c` set to `+`, I don't
see it.  The only loop I see is `while( std::cin >> c )`, and
this will either read a new character, or terminate.

If your goal is to just read a single line, it's probably better
to use `std::getline`, then iterate over the string you input:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) {
    //  Set up your stack here...
    for ( std::string::const_iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); ++ it ) {
        if ( isdigit( static_cast<unsigned char>( *it ) ) ) {
            //  process digit...
        } else if ( ispunct( static_cast<unsigned char>( *it ) ) ) {
            //  process punctuation, with eventually
            switch ( *it ) {
            case '+':
                //  addition...
                break;
            case '-':
                //  substraction...
                break;
            //  ...
            default:
                //  illegal operator...
                break;
            }
        } else {
            //  process anything else...
        }

    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define an `isOperator` function, along
the lines of:

```
bool
isOperator( char ch )
{
    static std::string const legalOps( "+-*/" );
    return std::find( legalOps.begin(), legalOps.end(), ch) != legalOps.end();
}
```